# Read and write embedded cover art to music files

Tags: id3, artwork

I am adding cover art support to the [Mixxx DJ mixing software](http://mixxx.org/). Code is written in Qt. I don't understand how to write code that will do the exact reading from and writing to files containing cover art. I can use external libraries to perform this task but it is required that the libraries are cross platform and preferably open-source. Libraries can be in any language. Adding dependencies to the existing software is not much of an issue.

Any links, suggestions, code will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I will use taglib to check whether embedded cover art is present. taglib is already a dependency for Mixxx and supports read/write of all the common formats for cover art ([mp4](http://taglib.github.io/api/classTagLib_1_1MP4_1_1CoverArt.html),[ID3v2](http://taglib.github.io/api/classTagLib_1_1ID3v2_1_1Tag.html#a5094b04654b0912db9dca61de11f4663)).